# Is there really a valid scenario for the new overload in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, new-operator

[image]

The example shows my scenario. I have a *BaseClass* with some nice functionality which is used by the derived class *SpecialClass*. But the *BaseClass* has a *Parent* of type *BaseClass*. The *SpecialClass* needs a *Parent* of the type *SpecialClass* because I do not want to cast - better safe cast - the parent every time I use it. To solve this scenario I used the keyword *new* to create a overload of this property. The same applies for *BaseConnection* and some other properties.

Unfortunate I hate this keyword and in my opinion it represents always the lack of a good design. But in this case I have clearly no idea how to better solve this problem. Does anyone have an idea?

Regards, Yggdrasil

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements fully, but you could consider making `BaseClass` generic - that would mean you wouldn't have to force the caller to explicitly cast.

Comment: @RGraham, good idea - here's hoping the parent is always the same type as the derived class.

Comment: @RGraham, I have updated the example. Parent is not the only property and I do not like the idea to have a generic parameter for all these properties. Additionally, I also use the BaseClass this would than be BaseClass<BaseClass> if I use generic here.

Comment: `new` is not an operator (it is in [tag:c++] though). Also, it doesn't create an overload: in fact it does the opposite.

Comment: @sehe, thx but that does not solve my problem. I know what new does, that is why I do not like to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use something like that (for example):

```
public class Base
{

    public virtual Base Parent { get {return ...}}

    public virtual BaseConnection Connection { get {return ... ;}}
}

public class Special : Base
{

    public override Base Parent { get {return MySpecialParent;}}

    public override BaseConnection Connection { get {return new SpecialConnection();}}
}
```

or even something like that (in case there is no relation between BaseConnection  and SpecialConnection):

```
public class Base
{

    public virtual dynamic Parent { get {return ...}}

    public virtual dynamic Connection { get {return ... ;}}
}

public class Special : Base
{

    public override dynamic Parent { get {return MySpecialParent;}}

    public override dynamic Connection { get {return new SpecialConnection();}}
}
```

But maybe you should give another thought about your class separations , maybe you should inject the specific relations to the Base class from it's creator or use some sort of container and work with interfaces instead . Just a thought ... :)

Comment: The first isn't an option because he says that he needs to access functionality of the derived class when accessing the parent of a derived class.  `dynamic` is just terrible design here, as it's turning off type safety entirely, when that's simply not appropriate.

Comment: True, the first option does not work, because I would need to cast again and the other option seems to me as dirty as the option with new, although I never used it.